# Working with fetched Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the keys `"-KTjDx_Ms255rS7GGT7l"` for my returned objects so I can access nested data? The data being returned to me from Firebase is one big object containing other objects. It looks like this.

```
{
    "-KTjDx_Ms255rS7GGT7l": {
        "questions": [
            { 
                "options": [
                      { "isAnswer":false,"text":"dfsf"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fffffff"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fsfsdfs"}
                 ],
                "text":"sdfsf"
            }
        ]
},
{
    "-KTjDx_Ms255rS7GGT7l": {
        "questions": [
            { 
                "options": [
                      { "isAnswer":false,"text":"dfsf"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fffffff"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fsfsdfs"}
                 ],
                "text":"sdfsf"
            }
     ]
},
{
    "-KTjDx_Ms255rS7GGT7l": {
        "questions": [
            { 
                "options": [
                      { "isAnswer":false,"text":"dfsf"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fffffff"} , {"isAnswer":false,"text":"fsfsdfs"}
                 ],
            "text":"sdfsf"
            }
         ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your data is called `firebaseResponse`:

```
Object.keys( firebaseResponse ).forEach( function( key ) {
    var item = firebaseResponse[ key ];
    item.questions ...
});
```

Comment: Hm. That's definitely what I should be doing but I'm getting `undefined` when trying to `console.log(item.questions)`

Comment: But `questions` is an array it seems. You should be accessing its properties by `index` as `console.log(item.questions[1])` for `text` field. @staxwell